# Tower defense: turret tracking enemy and shooting issues

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Here is my code:

```
func bombTowerTurnShoot() {
    var prevDistance:CGFloat = 1000000
    var closesetZombie = zombieArray[0]
        self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "bomb tower") {
            node, stop in
            if self.zombieArray.count > 0 {
            for zombie in self.zombieArray {
            if let bombTower = node as? SKSpriteNode {
                let angle = atan2(closesetZombie.position.x - bombTower.position.x , closesetZombie.position.y - bombTower.position.y)
                let actionTurn = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: -(angle - CGFloat(Double.pi/2)), duration: 0.2)
                bombTower.run(actionTurn)
                let turretBullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Level 1 Turret Bullet")
                turretBullet.position = bombTower.position
                turretBullet.zPosition = 20
                turretBullet.size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
                //turretBullet.setScale (frame.size.height / 5000)
                turretBullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: max(turretBullet.size.width / 2, turretBullet.size.height / 2))
                turretBullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                turretBullet.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Bullet //new contact
                turretBullet.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.None
                turretBullet.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Zombie
                self.addChild(turretBullet)
                var dx = CGFloat(closesetZombie.position.x - bombTower.position.x)
                var dy = CGFloat(closesetZombie.position.y - bombTower.position.y)
                let magnitude = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
                dx /= magnitude
                dy /= magnitude
                let vector = CGVector(dx: 4.0 * dx, dy: 4.0 * dy)
                func fire () {
                    turretBullet.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(vector)
                }
                func deleteBullet() {
                    turretBullet.removeFromParent()
                }
                turretBullet.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0), SKAction.run(fire), SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.0), SKAction.run(deleteBullet) ]))

                let distance = hypot(zombie.position.x - bombTower.position.x, zombie.position.y - bombTower.position.y)
                if distance < prevDistance {
                    prevDistance = distance
                    closesetZombie = zombie
                }


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What this code does is turns a turret towards the closest zombie and shoot at it. As far as I can tell the turret is turn towards the closest zombie (if you can tell whether this code actually accomplishes that or not I would like to know). The bigger problem I am having is that the turrets sometimes shoot more than one bullet. I think it is because it is trying to fire at all zombies in the array not the specified one (the closest to the tower). How can I make it so that the turret only shoots the zombie that is closest?

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {//new contact
     var zombieArray:[SKSpriteNode] = []
...
...
}
```

And I append all the zombie to the array once they are added and remove them from the array once they die.

Comment: we need the code for zombieArray declaration.

Comment: Just added it hope it helps.

Comment: it does help the question, but I've already answered your question below. Did you understand the need to separate actions into into two methods? `findClosestZombie` then `fireAtZombie`. Right now you are doing both of them with each iteration of your loop, and each iteration of your `self.enumeratedChildNodes`

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see your answer my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I don't know what you were doing wrong exactly. You had a ton of stuff going on, and trying to figure out the bug would probably have taken longer than rewriting it (for me at least). So that is what I did.

Here is a link to the project on github:

https://github.com/fluidityt/ShootClosestZombie/tree/master

For me, this was all about separating actions into somewhat distinct methods, and separating actions in general from logic.

You had so much going on, it was hard to test / see which parts were working correctly or not. This is where having somewhat smaller methods come in, as well as separating action from logic.. Your action may work fine, but perhaps it's not getting called due to a logic error.

So, how I implemented this was to just make your bomb turret it's own class.. that way we can have the bomb turret be in charge of most of its actions, and then let gameScene handle most of the implementation / and or logic.

The demo I've uploaded shows two turrets that auto-orient themselves to the closest zombie every frame, then shoot at them every second. Click the screen to add more zombies.

The turrets independently track the closest zombie *to them* so if you spawn a zombie on the left and the right, then the left turret will shoot at left zombie, and right turret will shoot at right zombie (and only once!).

[image]

```
class BombTower: SKSpriteNode {

  static let bombName = "bomb tower"

  var closestZombie: SKSpriteNode!

  func updateClosestZombie() {
    let gameScene = (self.scene! as! GameScene)
    let zombieArray = gameScene.zombieArray

      var prevDistance:CGFloat = 1000000
      var closestZombie = zombieArray[0]

      for zombie in zombieArray {

        let distance = hypot(zombie.position.x - self.position.x, zombie.position.y - self.position.y)
        if distance < prevDistance {
          prevDistance = distance
          closestZombie = zombie
        }
      }
    self.closestZombie = closestZombie
  }

  func turnTowardsClosestZombie() {
    let angle = atan2(closestZombie.position.x - self.position.x , closestZombie.position.y - self.position.y)
    let actionTurn = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: -(angle - CGFloat(Double.pi/2)), duration: 0.2)
    self.run(actionTurn)
  }

  private func makeTurretBullet() -> SKSpriteNode {
    let turretBullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Level 1 Turret Bullet")
    turretBullet.position = self.position
    turretBullet.zPosition = 20
    turretBullet.size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
    //turretBullet.setScale (frame.size.height / 5000)

    turretBullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: max(turretBullet.size.width / 2, turretBullet.size.height / 2))
    turretBullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    //    turretBullet.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Bullet //new contact
    //    turretBullet.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.None
    //    turretBullet.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Zombie

    return turretBullet
  }

  private func fire(turretBullet: SKSpriteNode) {
    var dx = CGFloat(closestZombie.position.x - self.position.x)
    var dy = CGFloat(closestZombie.position.y - self.position.y)
    let magnitude = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
    dx /= magnitude
    dy /= magnitude

    let vector = CGVector(dx: 4.0 * dx, dy: 4.0 * dy)

    turretBullet.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(vector)
  }

  func addBulletThenShootAtClosestZOmbie() {
    let bullet = makeTurretBullet()
    scene!.addChild(bullet)
    fire(turretBullet: bullet)
  }
}
```

---

```
// TODO: delete bullets, hit detection, and add SKConstraint for tracking instead of update.
// Also, I think that we are iterating too much looking for nodes. Should be able to reduce that.
// Also also, there are sure to be bugs if zombieArray is empty.
class GameScene: SKScene {

  var zombieArray: [SKSpriteNode] = []

  private func makeBombArray() -> [BombTower]? {
    guard self.zombieArray.count > 0 else { return nil }

    var towerArray: [BombTower] = []
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: BombTower.bombName) { node, _ in towerArray.append(node as! BombTower) }
    guard towerArray.count > 0 else { return nil }

    return towerArray
  }

  private func towersShootEverySecond(towerArray: [BombTower]) {

    let action = SKAction.run {
      for bombTower in towerArray {
        guard bombTower.closestZombie != nil else { continue } // I haven't tested this guard statement yet.
        bombTower.addBulletThenShootAtClosestZOmbie()
      }
    }
    self.run(.repeatForever(.sequence([.wait(forDuration: 1), action])))
  }

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    // Demo setup:
    removeAllChildren()

    makeTestZombie: do {
      spawnZombie(at: CGPoint.zero)
    }
    makeTower1: do {
      let tower = BombTower(color: .yellow, size: CGSize(width: 55, height: 55))
      let turretGun = SKSpriteNode(color: .gray, size: CGSize(width: 25, height: 15))
      turretGun.position.x = tower.frame.maxX + turretGun.size.height/2
      tower.name = BombTower.bombName
      tower.addChild(turretGun)
      addChild(tower)
    }
    makeTower2: do {
      let tower = BombTower(color: .yellow, size: CGSize(width: 55, height: 55))
      let turretGun = SKSpriteNode(color: .gray, size: CGSize(width: 25, height: 15))
      turretGun.position.x = tower.frame.maxX + turretGun.size.height/2
      tower.addChild(turretGun)
      tower.position.x += 200
      tower.name = BombTower.bombName
      addChild(tower)
    }

    guard let towerArray = makeBombArray() else { fatalError("couldn't make array!") }

    towersShootEverySecond(towerArray: towerArray)
  }

  private func spawnZombie(at location: CGPoint) {
    let zombie = SKSpriteNode(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width: 35, height: 50))
    zombieArray.append(zombie)
    zombie.position = location
    zombie.run(.move(by: CGVector(dx: 3000, dy: -3000), duration: 50))
    addChild(zombie)
  }

  // Just change this to touchesBegan for it to work on iOS:
  override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    let location = event.location(in: self)
    spawnZombie(at: location)
  }

  // I think this could be a constrain or action, but I couldn't get either to work right now.
  private func keepTowersTrackingNearestZombie() {
    guard let towerArray = makeBombArray() else { return }
    for tower in towerArray {
      tower.updateClosestZombie()
      tower.turnTowardsClosestZombie()
    }
  }

  override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    keepTowersTrackingNearestZombie()
  }
}
```

Comment: It still is shooting more than one bullet. I think it has to do with the closest zombie. Because I think it is sometimes able to find two separate closest zombie based on the code I wrote for determining the closest zombie. Is there any way to make the turret only choose one in that case? Or do you see how the function I have for finding the closest zombie is possibly flawed?

Comment: @B.Toaster yes. this code was not a working example, just to help show you what was going on. you need to split up processZombie into findClosest and shootAt. then put shootAt after you have foundClosest

Comment: you are finding and shooting multiple times because proceasZombie is called multiple times and processZombie both finds and shoots (needs splitting)

Comment: @B.Toaster ok this is a tower defense right? let me see if I can make something here that works..

Comment: Well yeah it is sort of like tower defense. Anyways thanks for the help and support. I've been working on this a while and have gotten stuck here for the past week.

Comment: @B.Toaster I just made a complete working project. let me upload it to github for you.

Comment: @B.Toaster I've completely re-written my answer and uploaded a working demo of tracking and shooting zombies. You will need to implement the gameplay logic such as scoring, healthpoints, and hit detection.

Comment: Thank you too much this was so helpful. The entire time I was trying to debug it I wasn't looking at the right thing! You really helped me out here.

Comment: @B.Toaster np. this was just a quick thing i put together so it may not be the most efficient on battery use etc. but I think it's a good starting point for you.